# Codeigniter http request and 404

Tags: codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I have a problem with Codeigniter.

This is my code:

http://pastebin.com/scccVP8D

If my url is: example.com/validator/validator/value/323445

Http request response:

323445

404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

Why do i get an error 404?

Comment: Can you give use your whole controller method please? I already see your validator method has no `value` paramater. That's why. But I need more to be completely sure.

Comment: The value parameter comes from url: /value/323445
Im using this Parameters Passing Technique: http://www.innovativephp.com/parameters-passing-techniques-in-codeigniter/

Comment: Problem solved: The name of class is not be match with method's name.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see value/323445 anywhere in your code. You just have function validator without any parameter.

So, when you call example.com/validator/validator/value/323445 the page don't egsist.

You need to delete parameter or to add parameter in function and to use it.